# Negation of sed regular expression

Tags: sed

I have a table in a text file with tab separator and I have a sed script that selects only those strings in my file that have 83, 86, 173, 163 in second column:

```
sed -n '/^[^\t]\+\t\(83\|89\|147\|163\)/p' test.txt
```

Now I want to select all the string that have anything else, but 83, 86, 173, 163 in second column. I've tried to put ^ in different places and tried to change p to d, but did't succeed.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: As long as you're using `sed` in 'p' mode, why not try `grep -v` for your task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem using ! before p:

`sed -n '/^[^\t]\+\t\(83\|89\|147\|163\)/!p' test.txt`

Comment: you can also use `sed '/^[^\t]\+\t\(83\|89\|147\|163\)/d' test.txt`... see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range/17103/negating-address-range#t=201611061139422082497 for more examples